# Microsoft Extension Framework add custom dimensions to the logger instead of each call?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-function-app, microsoft-extensions-logging

I have an azure function:

```
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * *", RunOnStartup =true)]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
     using (logger.BeginScope(properties))
     {
        logger.LogTrace(message);
     }           
}

Dictionary<string, object> _props = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "service", "exchange.rates.procces" } };
```

As you can see I add custom properties by providing a dictionary (properties) to BeginScope. Is there anyway to add the dictionary to the logger, so I do not have to provide the dictionary for each call? The logger write to Application Insigths.

Comment: can you show us the details of properties parameter of BeginScope method? and is it necessary to use BeginScope method?

Comment: I added the properties to post. I want to add my own custom dimensions in application insights. I only know to ways to do that. With BeginScope or like:  string lol1 = "lol1 text";
            string lol2 = "lol2 text";
            log.LogTrace("LogTrace {lol1}, {lol2}", lol1, lol2);

Comment: Have you refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1675)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add custom dimensions, you can take use of [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) for your azure function.

After writing your own ITelemetryInitializer, you need to register it in azure function. Please refer to the sample code below:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

//add thie line of code before namespace
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp2.MyStartup))]
namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1
    {

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {            
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            log.LogInformation("333 this is a test message...");
        }
    }

    //define your custom ITelemetryInitializer which is used to add custom dimension
    internal class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry != null && !telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("my_custom_dimen22"))
            {
                telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("my_custom_dimen22", "Hello, this is custom dimension for request!!!");
            }
        }
    }

    //register your custom ITelemetryInitializer
    public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();
        }
    }
}
```

The test result:

[image]